# Case Statement on Multiple conditions in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, case

```
CASE test
WHEN  NULL and  SUBSTR(('99999999' - Tst_Date),1,4) > 2009 THEN 'Medi'                     
WHEN   NULL and SUBSTR(('99999999' - Tst_Date),1,4) < 2009 THEN 'hills'
ELSE test
END AS "Phy"
```

Am i missing something in the above case statement?
I keep on getting 00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword" error?

Comment: the substring function is `substr` not `subsrt` as you have it

Comment: It was a typo. Sorry i edited the question now

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your syntax is a little bit off.  Use this:

```
CASE WHEN test IS NULL AND SUBSTR(('99999999' - Tst_Date),1,4) > 2009 THEN 'Medi'
     WHEN test IS NULL AND SUBSTR(('99999999' - Tst_Date),1,4) < 2009 THEN 'hills'
     ELSE test
END AS "Phy"
```